# How can I tell whether a Mac can already boot Windows?

Tags: mac, multi-boot

I've just been given a nearly new (used for a few weeks only) Mac by my uncle. How can I tell if it can already boot windows? He says he thinks it already can be he has no idea how. If it can't already boot Windows, how can I fix it so it can?

Comment: what kind of mac?

Comment: It's a MacbOok Pro

Answer (score 2):

If it uses an x86 processor- (you can check this in ['about my mac'](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1531), which all macs made anytime recently should, it should be able to run windows through [boot camp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) - which is the apple way of doing a dualboot. They also officially support versions between [XP to 7](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1899). The bootcamp page also has comprehensive information on how to do it.

I'm told its pretty simple, and should work without too many issues. Apple even provides windows drivers for the OS X filesystem and hardware.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to buy boot camp but I worry that maybe it's already been installed my the machine. Is there any way I can prove that it has not been?

Comment: Also in the FAQ http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1461 - under requirements "Boot Camp Assistant, which is located in /Applications/Utilities/ . You can also open Launchpad and type Boot Camp Assistant in the search field." Just see if its there.

Comment: Thanks, that's brilliant advice. I've got a ton of things in Launchpad, but none of them is called Boot Camp. Does this make it reasonable for me to conclude I don't have it?

Comment: I'd also check in that path to be sure. I'm not a mac user, but I was under the impression it was preinstalled, or very simple to install.

Comment: How can I check in that path?

Comment: Remember the folder to which thou goest when thou wantest an app that's not currently in thy dock?  Pull that up, and open the `Utilities` subfolder.  Boot Camp Assistant will either be present or absent.  Proceed as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

From the information you've given (like the fact that you have a MacBook Pro and launchpad), you can definitely *install* Windows via boot camp. Do note that you'll have to obtain a Windows license, which isn't cheap. **If you're wondering if Windows is already installed on your mac**, reboot your mac and hold down the option (alt) key; if you have dual-boot already set up you'll get more than one option int hat boot menu. Is that what you're asking?